# how to change the position of player using left and right button when the player is jumping?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

Cocos2d offers two ways to let the player jump up, but by using jumpto() and jumpby(), people could not change the position of the sprite any more when it is jumping up.

How to write a method so that the sprite can jump like the "Super Mario"?

Answer (score 2):

Some time ago I contributed some cocos2d code which made `CCMove` and `CCJump` actions stackable. See [here](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/pull/275). Starting from cocos2d 2.1, you can apply a `CCJump` actions concurrently with other movements.

However, if you want to deeply fine tune how the controls of your game feel, I'd avoid using `CCActions` altogether and I'd manage the `sprite.position` directly by processing player input.

Comment: Its correct. CCActions is good for animations, but not for gameplay. To move your player, the better way is change their sprite.position

Answer (score -1):

you have to check for **two condition** for making your player to jump, same as in Super Mario.

**Condition 1)** 
Only jump button is pressed at that time in CCJumpTo action you have to give the next position as the current position , height and no. jumps as one.

```
id jump = [CCJumpTo actionWithDuration:1 position:ccp(player.position.x, player.position.y)) height:20 jumps:1];
```

**Condition 2)** 
When jump and forward button is pressed at that time in CCJumpTo action you have to give the next position as the current position.x + the distance you want to cover by jump,this will be static all the time , height and no. jumps as one.

```
id jump = [CCJumpTo actionWithDuration:1 position:ccp(player.position.x+20, player.position.y)) height:20 jumps:1];
```

And at the end you have to run jump action on player, hope you found this as solution for your question...!!

Comment: I think that he is asking about changing direction of movement in the middle of a jump based on player input (input that arrives after the player has pressed the jump button). Your solution doesn't allow that.